# How can my application capture an image with the camera once the Activity has been started?

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to take a picture with the front camera as soon as the user logs into their device. My goals are to take a picture without the user knowing by starting the camera activity and taking a picture as soon as possible. I've followed the code from the [android website](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/camera.html#custom-camera) and I do have the application working.

Now I am trying to take a picture once the activity has started and this is currently in my `onCreate`:

```
 // Create our Preview view and set it as the content of our activity.
    mPreview = new CameraPreview(this, mCamera);
    final FrameLayout preview = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.camera_preview);
    preview.addView(mPreview);

    // Add a listener to the Capture button
    Button captureButton = (Button) findViewById(id.button_capture);
    captureButton.setOnClickListener(
        new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // get an image from the camera
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
            }       
        }
    );
```

but when I comment it out to replace it with just:

```
mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mPicture);
```

I get an error

```
04-10 15:03:11.006: E/AndroidRuntime(25729): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
 ComponentInfo{com.example.cameraactivity/com.example.cameraactivity.CameraActivity}:
 java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
```

I do not know why it does not work, is it because my `surfaceview` has not been started? and I am trying to take a picture too fast? I've put in a wait for 5 seconds and it didn't do the job.